# Select Count from same table returns different number

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am doing count functions on two separate columns, but from the table with different results. How is this possible as Count should include the `Null` values?

```
SELECT COUNT(Record_Id) FROM my_schema.table
```

Returns 40493

```
SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM my_schema.table
```

Returns 40249

Answer (score 1):

This isn't surprising.  `COUNT()` with an expression as an argument counts the number of non-`NULL` values.

Hence, this is saying that `Record_Id` is `NULL` six more times than `status`.

You can get the total number of records using `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: is there a function for counting nulls other than using a where clause?

Comment: @user2242044 . . . I don't know what you are asking.  `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows.  `COUNT(status)` counts the number of non-NULL status values.  `COUNT(*) - COUNT(status)` is one way of counting the number of `NULL` values (although I would use `SUM(status is null)` in MySQL for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

`count()` does not include NULL values. This is specifically for the purpose of counting non-null values, especially in complex queries with lots of outer joins.

If you want to get the number of rows, don't use count on a specific column, but simply use `COUNT(1)`, or any other scalar value that will get repeated for every row in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Null Values will not be counted if selecting count of a specific column. Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: what if I want to do a count with a group by and include nulls?

Comment: Use this format : select status,count (*) from table-name group by status